# find the non intersection between 2 list, including duplicate

Tags: python, multiset

I tried to look up this question before asking but could not find any satisfactory. so I have 2 list like this

```
a=[1,2,3,4,4]
b=[1,1,2,3,4]
```

I tried this:

```
set(a) - set(b)
```

but got this

```
set()
```

what I want is this

```
[1,4]
```

Since set a has 2 4s and set b has 2 1s. What can I do? Thank you!

Comment: *"set a has 2 4s"* - No, it doesn't, sets don't have duplicates, as soon as you use `set`, set a has one 4, likewise for set b with 1s

Comment: Yes, thank you, so what can I do?

Comment: But even if they were multisets (math term), then `set(a) - set(b)` would only have one element, 4. Please explain what you want because your output doesn't match your attempts.

Comment: What I want is a+b - (a∩b)

Comment: You should include your comment in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), is the Python implementation of a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset):

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
b = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
c = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]

counts_a = Counter(a)
counts_b = Counter(b)
counts_c = Counter(c)

result_b = (counts_a | counts_b) - (counts_a & counts_b)
result_c = (counts_a | counts_c) - (counts_a & counts_c)

print(list(result_b.elements()))
print(list(result_c.elements()))
```

**Output**

```
[1, 4]
[1, 1, 4]
```

Note that `(counts_a | counts_b) - (counts_a & counts_b)` is the Python equivalent of the mathematical formula.

Answer (score 2):

With `collections.Counter` object to compare occurrences of respective values:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4]
b = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
a_counts, b_counts = Counter(a), Counter(b)
res = [a_key for a_key, b_key in zip(a_counts, b_counts)
       if a_counts[a_key] != b_counts[b_key]]

print(res)   # [1, 4]
```